# Sound on Install 13.04

Tags: sound

Once I install 13.04 from 12.10 the sound on my LG laptop stopped working. I installed 13.10 hoping the bug was fixed but alas while the sound worked the laptop keyboard wouldn't work. Any ideas? I upgraded from 12.10 originally because of problems with my second screen. Are these known bugs or am I doing something wrong? It appears I will have to stick to good old Windows for some time yet.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended resource is the [Official Ubuntu Sound Troubleshooting guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting).

In case you still face an issue you should take a look at the sound guide discussed in Ubuntuforums.org
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=205449